# how to create a get request with angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a service that does a get request in angular. I got this error: Http does not exist.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class CoursesService {

    constructor(private http: Http) {

        this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
    }

    getCourses() {

        //return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
        return ["math", "chemistry", "physics"];

    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: `constructor(private http: Http)` -> `constructor(private http: HttpClient)`

Comment: As @Thatkookooguy says, inject the `HttpClient`. You also need to make sure the corresponding module (often `AppModule`) imports the `HttpClientModule`.

Comment: could somebody tell me what the return  type of the get request is . how would I display each user with a ngforloop

Comment: @masterinex the return type is an observable. Your IDE should have intellisense to tell you such information.  Please refer to https://angular.io/guide/http for full documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You are importing `HttpClient` but then using `Http` (which is not referencing to anything) in the constructor. Use `private http: HttpClient` instead.

Comment: Making sure to import `HttpClientModule` in the corresponding module!

Comment: @WillAlexander, of course, but that's outside of the scope of the question.

Comment: If someone truly doesn't know how to use `HttpClient` in Angular, odds are they aren't aware of the necessity to import the module. I upvoted your answer because it is correct, and simply added the comment to make everything complete.